# Latex software used by MO

Tags: support, mathjax

What is the software used by MO to "render" Latex? Is it an outside solution or a software that has been written specifically? Interesting is that I understand that it doesn't produce images but texts with "sophisticated" fonts.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 11):

This site uses [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to display mathematical formulas. MathJax is an open source Javascript library, so this is an external solution.

Stack Exchange is a [MathJax partner](http://www.mathjax.org/stack-exchange-continues-as-mathjax-partner-2/) and recently donated $20,000 to support MathJax development. SE also tests beta versions of new MathJax releases on the Math.SE site. So while the library itself is independent, SE does support the development.